# android openPanel menu is empty

Tags: android, activitygroup

I have a tabActivity with multiple activities in one tab.

The following code work on android 2.3 but it's not working on android 4.2

**ActivityStack.java**

```
public class ActivityStack extends ActivityGroup {
..

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // // what is the current activity?
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "holder");

    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // start a new
    menu.clear();
    // add some menu options
    getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity().onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

..
**Activity1Tab1.java**

```
here I have a button from where I am calling Activity2Tab1.java onClickListener
Intent acIntent = new Intent();
                    acIntent.setClass(getParent(),
                            Activity2Tab1.class);
                    ActivityStack activityStack = (ActivityStack) getParent();
                    activityStack.push("SecondActivity", acIntent);
```

**Activity2Tab1.java**

```
..
here I have multiple layouts...defined
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    { //add menus or inflate here
        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepareOptionMenu");
        if (!isMainMenuVisible) {
            pushMainMenuUp();
        } else {
            pushMainMenuDown();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Need some help!!!

Neither in **Activity1Tab1** or in **Activity2Tab1** the override method **onKeyUp()** IS NEVER CALLED. The only called methods are from StackActivity. WHY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research done and some thinking I manage to make this code work.

Instead of using onPrepareOptionMenu(menu) and onCreateOptionMenu(menu) I've override the following method in StackActivity:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, keyCode+"");
         getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity().onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
```

and in Activity1Tab1 and Activity2Tab1 I had the method:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, ""+event.getAction());
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MENU_BUTTON_PRESSED");

        if (!isMainMenuVisible) {
            pushMainMenuUp();
        } else {
            pushMainMenuDown();
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);

}
```